# Safe area guide layout for iOS 8

Tags: xcode, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide

I have an application supporting iOS 8 and above versions. How can I manage UI of it so it is perfect in iPhoneX also?

[image]

Comment: see this for e.g : https://useyourloaf.com/blog/safe-area-layout-guide/